# How does D3's projection function work for paths and points?

Tags: d3.js

My understanding of D3's projection functions are that they do the same thing as the scale functions. They map GPS coordinates to pixel coordinates. This is the projection I'm currently using. (I don't understand all the variables in detail but I fiddled around with them until the map showed up)

```
 var projection = d3.geo.albers()
                .center([-122.436269,37.798107])
                .rotate([0, 0, 0])
                .parallels([36, 38])
                .scale(300000);
```

This draws the map fine:

```
.attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(projection))
```

When I try to plot points though the numbers are crazy.

```
.attr("cx",function(d) {
     return projection([d._lon,d._lat])[0];
})
.attr("cy",function(d) {
     return projection([d._lon,d._lat])[1];
});
```

How do I properly do this?

Here are some examples of the points I'm getting through the projection function:

```
[5175.3799972560955, 1808.5108650794136] 
[5158.315547249338, 1823.564395627589] 
[5143.958532762888, 1831.9879789081751]
```

On a 1280x800 screen these are way off. Even if I scale them by dividing by 100, they'll still mostly just stack on top of each other. I have a 700*700 svg positioned using twitter bootstrap. Not sure how those are taken into account. I just assumed that if the map if fine, then the same projection should work for the points.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. Can you give us an example of the "crazy" values you get?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yeah sure, just added some more info

Comment: Your scale value looks quite large. Could you provide a complete example please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I actually have it currently hosted at dlwjiang.site44.com. I thought it was large as well but I just assumed it was what was needed to show a city. (Most examples I've seen are on the level of continents or countries)

Comment: Did you verify that the point coordinates you have are correct?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Some of the points are out of the scope of the map but some are within. The thing is though that some points are showing, yet being shown incorrectly, and often stacked on top of each other. For example -122.6 and -122.5 would be quite a long line on the earth, but after the projection they become something like 500.1234 and 500.1235 which in pixels is the same position.

Comment: With a scale as large as yours that pixel difference seems possible. Maybe your path coordinates are wrong and not the points?